# I am trying to create a dynamic date statement to query rows containing dates between 3 months ago and yesterday (inclusive)

Tags: date, dynamic

I assume that this will be accomplished in the where portion of the query, but i am not sure how to create the dynamic portion for the query.

Comment: What type of database?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server - using tsql

Answer (score 0):

For TSQL, you're looking to use the [DATEADD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function.

`SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE datecol >= DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())
  AND datecol <= DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())`

Truncating `getdate()` will get you to midnights as needed.

Comment: This is perfect, simple and effective, Thanks for the insight Steegness

Comment: Ok here's a more indepth question.  I want this query to always pull 3 full months of weekly PLUS the week-to-date total for the current period.  I also want to display the sales orders by week, rather then day or month

Comment: If you dig the answer, vote it up and mark it as accepted! :)

I don't quite get your constraints there.  The first line of the WHERE goes back three months from right this second (and therefore has week-to-date).  Can you give an example of what you're expecting if you ran the query right now?

Comment: Display is going to be a function of what you select.  Check out FORMAT() : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: Ok here is an example of the data i would expect to see if i ran today:  Sales order data from Monday July 20 (our fiscal calendar is Monday to Sunday) through to today (Wednesday October 21).  As far as the

Comment: As far as the display by week portion, let me clarify, currently the data is displayed by order on a specific date, i want the output of the query to return data in weekly groupings rather then individual orders or by day or by month.